# select is not valid at this position for this server version expecting '(' with

Tags: mysql, sql

how can I fix this error : select is not valid at this position for this server version expecting '(' with
I just have this syntax :

```
SELECT t1.id as ID, t1.1  as GID FROM t1;
```

1 is my column name. As, I have more than 100 columns I named them as 1,2,3,... and so on 
I use SQL workbench version 8.0.11 with Mac 
Will there be any problems If I have my column names to be 1,2,3, and etc?

Comment: No, I tried.Did not help

Comment: Sounds like you may have to put backticks around the column name

Comment: Naming columns numbers is a really bad plan. This will irritate people to no end if you can't fix it.